# All possible ways getting from [0,0,0] to [30,30,30]

Tags: java, permutation

For a game Tribal Wars, I would like to know how I can solve following problem: There are 3 buildings starting at level 0. You can upgrade a building, increasing it's level from 0 to 1, to a maximum of 30.

Since you can upgrade your building independent of the levels of the other buildings, there are 30*30*30 combinations of the buildinglevels...

The output for these combinations would be:

```
0/0/0  
0/0/1  
0/0/2  
...  
0/0/30  
0/1/0  
[0,1,1]  
...  
0/1/30  
0/2/0  
0/2/1  
...  
0/2/30  
...  
0/30/0  
...  
0/30/30]  
1/0/0
```

And so on, up to 30/30/30...

The code for this output would be a simple loop-in-a-loop-in-a-loop!

BUT: This is not what we want!

What I want is the way to get to these combinations e.g. to combination [1,1,1] there are 6 (= !3) possible ways to reach this combination (with "a" = upgrading the first building, "b" = upgrading the 2nd building and "c" upgrading the 3rd building):

```
a -> b -> c  
a -> c -> b  
b -> a -> c  
b -> c -> a  
c -> a -> b  
c -> b -> a
```

Note, that these 6 ways all lead to the same result – all buildings were upgraded once. Now, to reach level 30 on all buildings, I have to upgrade every one of them 30 times, which means in the end we made 30*3 upgrades.

A way to get there would for example be:

```
a -> a -> a -> ... -> a -> b -> b -> ... -> b -> c -> ... -> c
```

What I think I need is an Array with 90 elements, containing 3 elements (each 30 times), and then I need every possible order of these 90 elements...

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

M. M.

Comment: This is unclear. Could you post a sample of the wanted output? Also something you have tried?

Comment: Start by writing some code, encounter a difficulty, document it, try and solve it by looking online. If you fail after all this, write a MCV example and post it here. Welcome

Comment: This sounds simply like a permutation/combination problem. You haven't shown any of what you've already tried

Comment: How will there be only 90 upgrades? Shouldn't there be 30*30*30?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what youre looking for but:

```
// you can store whatever you desire for these buildings
int[][][] buildings = new int[30][30][30]; 

// go through each possible level combination and print it
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
      for(int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
           buildings[i][j][k]; // at this point, do whatever you want with the array
           System.out.println("Building1: " + "i + " Building2: " + j " " + " Building3 " + k);
      }
   }
}
```

If all you're looking for is the print out of the possible level schemes, then you can remove the `buildings` array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well and one can upgrade building from one level to the other without others building being on certain level there's more possibilities. There are actually 31*31*31 possible ways the buildings can be build.

If that's what you meant here's simple nested for loop:

```
    for (int a = 0; a <= 30; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 30; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c <= 30; c++) {
                System.out.println("Building A: " + a + " Building B: " + 
                        b + " Building C: " + c);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
Now I see what you are looking for. Your problem is actually graph traversal. You want to look for all possible paths from node [0,0,0] to node [30, 30, 30]. In that case you have to implement simple search algorithm. I recommend Depth First Search or Breadth First Search. Links to their pages on Wikipedia (you will find there pseudo-code)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Hope it helps

Comment: It should be variable < 30, not less than or equal since you start at 0 which would cause 31 iterations.

Comment: I believe the building starts on level 0 and can be upgraded to level 30. So there are 31 levels available in total.